# How to pass and get array as an argument to shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I am passing multiple argument to a shell script.
I that script I want to create an array from 2nd argument till the last argument.
This I am able to do with below -

```
arg=$1
shift
while [[ $1 != '' ]]
do
        emailID[${#emailID[@]}]=$1
shift
done
```

This emailID array I want to pass to second script as second argument and I want to retrieve the array in this second script.
Is there a way to do it in ksh/bash?

Comment: From the [tag:shell] tag wiki, it seems like it shouldn't be used with the [tag:bash] tag. Did you have a reason to put them together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `${@:2}`. It is explained [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_expansion) perfectly.

And to pass it into another script:

```
./anotherScript "${@:2}"
```

Of course it will not pass it as array (because you cannot pass an array), but it will pass all elements of that array as individual parameters.

---

Okay, lets try it this way. Here is your first script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Here is my awesome first argument: $1"
var=$1 # I can assign it into a variable if I want to!
echo 'Okay, and here are my other parameters!'
for curArg in "${@:2}"; do
    echo "Some arg: $curArg"
done
myArr=("${@:2}") # I can assign it into a variable as well!

echo 'Now lets pass them into another script!'
./anotherScript 'Wheeee' "${@:2}"
```

And here is your another script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Alright! Here we can retrieve some arguments!'
echo "Here we go: $@" # that is including 'Wheeee' from the previous script. But we can use the same trick from above if we want to.
```

Comment: Hi Aleks, How to retrive this array in second script?

Comment: @user3780855 if it's the only parameter the other script takes, just use `arrayvar=("$@")`. If the other script takes other arguments, you'll have to figure out a way to tell it where the array starts and ends. The parameters are really just a series of words, there's no standard way to say "parameters 3 through 7 are an array". If you want more help on this, you'll have to tell us more about the other script and its arguments.

Comment: Hi Gordon, As i said I want to do something like this - b="${@:2}"./anotherScript $a $b And in  another script - If i have to retrive the array then how do i do it? is this the correct way? anotherScript - var=$1; array="${@:2}"

Comment: @GordonDavisson Well, if you want to use parameters 3 through 7 as an array you can just use ``"${@:3:5}"``.

Comment: Hi Aleks and Gordan, I was able to do it with aleks's way-
`./anotherScript $a ${emailID[*]}
anotherScript -
emailID="${@:2}"`

Thanks @Aleks-Daniel Jakimenko and @Gordon Davisson

Comment: @user3780855 It is incorrect. You have to quote variables like so ``./anotherScript "$a" "${emailID[@]}"``, also ``@`` makes more sense here. Also ``emailID="${@:2}"`` does not give you an array, it will be a string. If you want it to be an array then do ``emailID=("${@:2}")``

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
arg="$1"
shift
emailID=( "$@" )
```

The second assignment makes an array out of the remaining arguments.  You might get away without the quotes around `$1` these days; it was not always thus and I use double quotes for consistency.

You can then pass the array to the second script:

```
second_script "${emailID[@]}"
```

However, it is up to the second script to decide whether to treat the arguments as an array.  There is no difference between that and passing a number of separate arguments.  You can't distinguish the array from arguments before or after the array.

Comment: ``$@`` is an array already, so why would you want to create another array out of it? Well, if you want to modify its elements, then OK.

Comment: In which shell do you think it is an array?

Comment: The question is marked as ``bash`` so I mean bash. It depends on the definition of 'array', but basically it works exactly like that.

Comment: The characteristic array indexing notation `${@[1]}` does not work with `$@` in either Bash 3 or Bash 4.  I would suggest that `$@` is not an array, therefore.  Further, the section on [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the Bash manual makes it clear that that 'substringing' notation has a special meaning when applied to `$@`, but it is a special case, and is not related to array notation at all.

Comment: Sure, because you should use ``$1`` instead. With the same luck you can say that ``$$`` is not a variable because you cannot assign it (``$=2000``), but hey, everything else works! (Like ``"${$:0:2}"``)

Comment: We must be using two different dialects of English.

Comment: I'm just saying that you can treat ``$@`` as an array in most cases, unless you want to change its values. Technically you're right, it is not exactly an array, but it is enough array-ish that we can skip that part. You see, all other parameter expansions will work on it like if it was an array, try ``echo "${@^}"`` for example.

Comment: +1 for a concise, to-the-point answer. In bash, not quoting the RHS of an assignment if it's a single parameter/variable reference has worked since _at least_ version 3.1 - couldn't find any reference to it in the [terse bash changelog](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS), so it may _always_ have worked. However, I agree that it's good practice to double-quote.

Comment: Re slicing ('substringing') `$@` vs. arrays: the notation _is_ the same, so @Aleks-DanielJakimenko has a point when he says that `$@` can be treated like an array in most cases, except the inability to assign to elements with `${@[n]}`. Another noteworthy difference, however, is that  `$@` is effectively _1_-based ($1 refers to the _first_ positional parameter), unlike zero-based-by-default arrays.

Comment: @mklement0: I've not checked the Bash change logs either; assignment without quotes may always have worked in Bash.  Indeed, I just tried the Heirloom (Bourne) Shell, and it seems that the assignment works there without quotes, somewhat to my surprise.  I can't go back and resurrect the machines from the early 80s where I learned shell to determine whether I'm misremembering after all these years.  The 1978 paper on the Bourne shell doesn't illustrate what happens with `x="1 2"; y=$x`.