# how to get argument value in shell script passed from servlet

Tags: shell

I am trying to pass an argument from a servlet to a shell script.
I want to retrieve the values in a shell script to run commands.

Can anybody tell me how to retrive the passed argument in the shell script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass and get array as an argument to shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522187/how-to-pass-and-get-array-as-an-argument-to-shell-script)

Comment: Fixed some grammar and some formatting

Answer (score 0):

Use a dollar sign to get the argument passed to the shell script,

```
$#
```

"#" refers to the number of arguments specified on a command line.